# Facebook Graph API attachments image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If you check the image in the graph APi with query

102988293558_10152876958813559?fields=attachments

you will see that the image is not complete. its half cut and the right hand side of the picture is missing.. How can this be fixed? is there some other place from where I can retrieve a better image?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `full_picture` field instead. AFAIK this is not documented anywhere, but Graph API Explorer autocomplete suggests this field when you try to start typing "picture" into the "search for a field" box.

[102988293558_10152876958813559?fields=full_picture](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=102988293558_10152876958813559%3Ffields%3Dfull_picture&version=v2.2)

The URL this delivers for `full_picture` should point to the largest version of the image available, without any cropping applied.

Comment: but this field contains a very small image at times like in this case: 107238907460_10152440962127461?fields=full_picture